# Is this possible to use angular 2 in an non-restful project ? i.e. replacing thymeleaf and keep the rest of the projects java code as it is?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, single-page-application

I am going to start a web project for a secured / banking / financial application which will be a public website (website, open for all). My first preference was to use angular 2 as front end and spring boot as backend using oauth2 authentication.

**Problem 1 : I didn't get any secured place to store the access-token in my browser.**

Now I may develop a spring boot web project using thymeleaf as well as spring security & consume the REST apis from backend.(Access-Tokens will be stored against session) Thus I will be able to keep the access token separated from browser / client end.

**Problem 2 : I don't want to use Thymeleaf rather it would be great if I could use angular.**

Is this possible to use angular in this non-rest architecture?
Infact I just want to replace thymeleaf and consume spring boot @Controller by Angular and generate view from spring boot.

Comment: Of course! Thymeleaf is just a template engine, so you can replace it with Angular. And I don't recommend you to use thymleaf as front-end, it is too simple to handle complex requirements. A simple way is to put all the files (in `dest` folder under your Angular project) into `src/main/resource/static` folder, then you can run it as a single application with few code modification.